# email distribution list through website

Tags: email, hosting

I'm looking for a commercial option for managing email distribution groups through a website. Members need to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe from distribution lists, but crucially, they need to be able to send emails to the group themseleves (unlike newsletter signups like constant contact).

I understand this kind of thing is possible through open source options such as mailman, LISTSERV, ecartis, majordomo etc. However, I'm not keen on installing python scripts, working with beta, unsupported versions etc.

I'm after a commercial, hosted solution which gives me an API that I can plug my website into. The API would need options to set up new groups and subscribe to and from them.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work: http://documentation.mailgun.net/api-mailinglists.html? If not, send us an email with feedback.

Comment: Uncanny - I just found this too. Yes, I think this may do the job. Still interested in any alternatives at this stage. Thank you!